# Player animation is not working while taking in game controller input but works while taking in keyboard input

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

Coding in c# and using the XNA 4.0 framework I am trying to develop for both keyboard and game controller input when it comes to player control.

My code for the game controller input is as follows;

```
GamePadState gamepadState = GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One); 

if(gamepadState.ThumbSticks.Left.X != 0 || gamepadState.ThumbSticks.Left.Y != 0) 
{   
     //Handles rotation
     angle += thumbsticksMove(gamepadState); //handles Left.X and Left.Y input
     normalize(); //normalizes angle and sets normalizedAngle = angle
     this.Rotate(normalizedAngle); //takes value and passes it through Math helper
     //atan and pi*2
     //Ends handles rotation

     pos += (angle * speed);

     //Implementing framerate adjustment just for this class
     timeSinceLastFrame += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
     if (timeSinceLastFrame > millisecondsPerFrame)
     {
          timeSinceLastFrame -= millisecondsPerFrame;
          Animation();
     }
}
```

This moves the player as expected and the sprite flips to the proper direction, but the animation piece does **not** work.  The sprite is supposed to animate with player movement upon input.  This works great when taking in input from the keyboard, see below;

```
if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
{
       input = Vector2.Zero;
       input.X = 1;

       //Handles rotation
       angle.X = input.X;
       normalize();
       this.Rotate(normalizedAngle);
       //Ends handles rotation

       pos += (input * speed);
       //Implementing framerate adjustment just for this class
       timeSinceLastFrame += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
       if (timeSinceLastFrame > millisecondsPerFrame)
       {
       timeSinceLastFrame -= millisecondsPerFrame;
       Animation();
       }
}
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out why it works for the keyboard input but not the game controller input.  It almost looks as if it's trying to animate but never quite makes it past the 3rd animation cell or animates so fast to the point of looking as if it's barely animating.  Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: I think we would need to see the `Animation()` code, or perhaps a full working example of the keyboard code to have a better idea of what is going wrong.

Comment: It seems like `timeSinceLastFrame -= millisecondsPerFrame;` should be `timeSinceLastFrame = 0f;`

Comment: Question has been updated with complete keyboard code example added.

Comment: There's still a lot of code hidden from us. We'd need to see the code for `Animation()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding

```
if (gamepadState.IsConnected){//Gamepad code}

if (!gamepadState.IsConnected){//Keyboard code}
```

Reading the inputs separately seems to have fixed the issue.

Thanks for everyone's help though.